# Amazon RDS - Can't connect to MySQL Server database?

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to login to MySQL server using *nix shell prompt, following is my command :

```
$ mysql ********** -east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
```

(where the asterisks are my ID)

I am getting following error :

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
```

Should I be specifying a username? If so, a username from where? And the password? I already created Security Groups, but I'm not sure how to relate them to logging onto the server.

Comment: i think you need an "h" between the dash and the hostname or else mysql thinks you want localhost

Comment: ''@'localhost' error message specify that username is blank or anonymous, Please specify username of database using -u option of MySQL

Answer (score 2):

To connect to a DB instance using the MySQL

Type the following command at a command prompt to connect to a DB instance using the MySQL monitor; substitute the DNS name for your DB instance.

```
  PROMPT> mysql -h myinstance.mydnsnameexample.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p
```

Answer (score 0):

1)By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user,may be Amazon has droped anonymous user

2)in MySQL,localhost,ip,127.0.0.1 are differ,but by default,MySQL login with localhost,you might as well try -h